# How to convert datetime for google rich card

Tags: php

I need  change to   **July 25,2017**  time to   **2017-25-07T08:00:00+08:00**

`$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );`

**Result:** `2017-25-07T08:00:00+08:00

//this format will be show result`

Answer (score 0):

You can change date into every format,

For Month day,year (**July 25,2017**) Use

```
<?php
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
$newdate=date('F d,Y',strtotime($mysqldate)); 
echo $newdate; 
?>
```

For Short Month name (**Jul 25,2017**) use

```
<?php
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
$newdate=date('m d,Y',strtotime($mysqldate)); 
echo $newdate; 
?>
```

for more visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks brother 